# Trigger audio files based on a method call or other variables

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am designing a game that changes scenes as the user is playing. The scenes change based on a NSTimer. I can ge everything to change accordingly in regards to graphics. Can even get background music to change.

Where I seem to be hitting a roadblock is changing the score sound and the sound for when the player collides with an object and dies.

As it it's right now I can cancel the sound for scene one but cannot get another one to play. 
*** on phone don't know how to hand code a code block on here***

```
If([_timer isValid]) {

//plays correct audio and does not       continue when scene changes
}
Else if ([_timer == nil ]){
//suppose to play other sound but does nothing. 
}
```

I would really prefer to call the different sounds based on if a method is called to change  something along the lines of

```
Else if ([ _method1 == TRUE]) {
//play sound
}
```

Any advice in the right direction appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
if( _moving.speed > 0 ) {
    if( ( contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask & scoreCategory ) == scoreCategory || ( contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask & scoreCategory ) == scoreCategory ) {
        // has contact with score entity

        _score++;
        _scoreLabelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _score];

        //Pick Up Egg

        //Sound for Score

        SKAction* teslaPoint = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Point1" waitForCompletion: YES];
        [self runAction:teslaPoint withKey:@"teslaPoint"];
```

I have been trying to structure an IF statement based on the background image because that changes with the sounds.

**EDIT**

```
        _scoreSound = [SKAudioNode node];
        SKAudioNode* teslaPoint = [SKAudioNode nodeWithFileNamed:@"Point1"];
        [_scoreSound addChild:teslaPoint];
```

**EDIT**
THIS IS ADDED IN initwithSize:
        _scoreSound = [SKNode node];
        [self addChild:_scoreSound];

Then its called in the contacts

**EDIT**

```
    //Sound for Score
    if([_timer isValid]){
        SKAction* teslaPoint = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Point1" waitForCompletion:YES];
        [self runAction:teslaPoint withKey:@"teslaPoint"];
    }

        if ([_bgImage  isEqual: @"bgimage2.png"]){


        SKAction* teslaPoint = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"grassypoint" waitForCompletion:YES];
        [self runAction:teslaPoint withKey:@"teslaPoint"];


    }
```

Comment: When dealing with sprite kit, it is best to avoid NSTimer,  SpriteKit has its own functions built inside that coincide with other functions that the scene provides.  As for answering your question,  I am having a hard time grasping what you are trying to do here,   What are you using to play your sound filed?

Comment: What can I use instead of NSTimer? I tried to base it on the score the player has with the label node but to no success which is why I used a timer.  I am using avaudioplayer. It plays one sound when the player gets a point on one scene but I need the sound to change when the images in the scene change.

Comment: `SKNode` has a `playSoundFileNamed` method, or you can use `SKAudioNode`, as for timer issues, you can use a sequence of `SKAction.waitForDuration` and `SKAction.runBlock`

Comment: Will try the waitForDuration. But is it possible to have the sounds change based on scene variables? Once maybe the block has been run or perhaps based on the background image files?

Comment: just add a new SKNode that plays the file, pause/remove the old one

Comment: Will try when I get back to my computer. Thanks for the info

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the ticket either. Because the Score entity is called every time a point is made, causing the audio file to be played even though the method called by the NSTime (haven't fiddled with that yet) stopped the play.

Comment: What are you talking about? You call pause on the node,  the audio stops playing

Comment: I added a block of code up top. To stop it I added removeActionForKey

Comment: removing the action does not guarantee it stopping on some devices IIRC,  you need to either remove the node from the scene, or just pause the node

Comment: Getting a terminating app error when it tries to add node to parent. See edits. Never used AudioNodes before.

Comment: don't use audio nodes, just use SKNodes for now, you can learn audio nodes later, and do not play sounds on the scene, play it on a separate node

Comment: `let sndPoint1Node = SKNode(); sndPoint1Node.playSoundFileNamed(....)`

Comment: I'm sorry KnightOfDragon I really just don't understand. Even playing it on a node still terminating the app from a nil child to parent. Ia appreciate al the help thus far,

Comment: well that means you didn't add the node to the scene

Comment: _scoreSound = [SKNode node];
            SKNode* teslaPoint = [SKNode nodeWithFileNamed:@"Point1"];
            [_scoreSound addChild:teslaPoint];

Comment: nodeWithFileNamed means you have a Point1.sks file

Comment: _scoreSound = [SKNode node];
            SKNode* teslaPoint = [SKNode playSoundFileNamed:@"point1" waitForCompletion:YES];
            [_scoreSound addChild:teslaPoint]; No know class methods for selector "playSoundFileNamed...."

Comment: oh sorry, that is my fault, it is `SKAction *snd = [SKAction playsoundFileNamed:];`  `[sndPointNode.runAction: snd]`

Comment: That gets it to work again. However even when the action is stopped when the scene changes that method gets called overtime a point is made causing the action to be added again. Now there are two sounds playing when a point is made.  Can I get each sound to trigger off of something else within the code?

Comment: well if the sound is being added back into the scene then you have a logic problem, find out why it is adding it, and do not add it

Comment: It has to be added every time because it's called in a method that is repetitively called as the player scores. Is there a way to call it off of background images? See edits (I'm trying it but it is not working as of this second)

Comment: if you get off of using the timer then it wouldn't matter because your actions would be be playing when switching scenes

Comment: But how would that solve the issue? If you do not mind elaborating

Comment: The scene itself is not changing so to speak, it is just changing graphical content within the scene. It's not phasing to a new .m file if thats what your saying.

Comment: you said changing scenes

Comment: You are correct it is my fault. As this conversation goes on, I am thinking that may be an easier avenue to completely recreate the scenes accordingly